# DC 12V to AC inverter, can make a product to dual voltage 110V and 220V in a single inverter?

Tags: inverter

I have searched quite a while for a nice
DC 12V to AC inverter, should have dual voltage 110V and 220V output in a single inverter (with universal sockets)? but not seeing options yet, I see many ones saying dual voltage, but actually have 110V version or 220V version, they're not in a single inverter, wonder is it some technical difficulty or something else, just being un-popular?

Update: It's because from the years international travel I have collected quite some small appliances, like hair dryer bought when was in Switzerland (1000 watts working with ~230V only), and electric cooker from Japan (600 watts working with ~110V only), I will continue have many international travel like 3months in UK, 2 months in Japan, 2 months in Africa; want to make all them work at some off-grid 12V DC lithium battery powered places, wonder is there an easy DC 12V to AC dual 110V 220V voltage in a single inverter?

For example, this product https://amzn.to/2RSJmmN can convert DC 12V to AC 110V, or DC 24V to AC 220V;  can I have 2 set of 12V batteries in series to get DC 24V, then easy to have both AC 220V (when two batteries in series), or AC 110V (when two batteries in parallel)?

and the above product is 5000W Power Inverter DC 12V to AC 110V, costs $65, now I am willing to pay 2x cost for two products, one for 110V output and one for 220V output, can any vendor make the two in a single product? (to save space/weight when traveling) is 2x cost enough to make such a single product?   or 3x costs?

Comment: It would be possible by adding a heavy center tapped transformer for 50 or 60 Hz.

Comment: A 220 V one, skills and time you can probably make it output 110 V, but same current do half the power.

Comment: there seems to be no shortage of split phase inverters,  do  you have some special extra requirement not mentioned here.  eg: AIMS PICOGLF40W12V240VS

Comment: IT WOULD BE "EASY ENOUGH" TO DO TECHNICALLY BUT ADDS COST. THE DEMAND PRESUMABLY DOES NOT WARRANT IT,.

Comment: for example I bought this before, it can both DC input 12V or 24V, convert to AC 110V or 220V accordingly, can I put two set of DC 12V batteries in series or parallel (or single) to easy create 12V or 24V DC then get 110V or 220V in a single product?     =============> DC to AC Car Power Inverter 120W DC 12V 24V to AC 110V 220V Car Charger Adapter with 3 AC Outlets Dual Cigarette Lighter Digital Monitor 4 USB Charging Ports for Phones Tablets Laptops Kindle (Black2) by Ansee https://amzn.to/2vj5tLR